# Riches or Divinity? (Revelation 5:12)

Tags: translation-philosophy, manuscript, latin-vulgate

Comparing some versions I have of the book of Revelation, I've come across two different words for (possibly) the same attribute: some versions (KJV, ASV, Darby etc.) say "riches" just after "power": "Worthy is the Lamb that was slain to receive power, and *riches*, and wisdom...," but other versions (such as Wycliffe, Fillion [French], Douay-Rheims etc.) read "divinity": "The Lamb that was slain is worthy to receive power and *divinity* and wisdom..." At first I thought it might had something to do with the Vulgate or some differences in the manuscripts, but I couldn't find any good answers so far.

Comment: Good question and a good recognition that the difference of translation might well be in the different languages - Latin/Greek. Up-voted +1. Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below, bottom left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: One meaning for the Greek word πλοῦτος [Strong 4149](https://biblehub.com/greek/4149.htm) is 'fulness' which, in the New Testament, is seen as an attribute of divinity.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all modern versions of the NT are translations of the Greek text.  In Rev 5:12, that Greek text is essentially undisputed.  It reads:

> λέγοντες φωνῇ μεγάλῃ Ἄξιόν ἐστιν τὸ ἀρνίον τὸ ἐσφαγμένον λαβεῖν τὴν
> δύναμιν καὶ πλοῦτον καὶ σοφίαν καὶ ἰσχὺν καὶ τιμὴν καὶ δόξαν καὶ
> εὐλογίαν. = saying with a loud voice, "Worthy is the Lamb that was
> slain to receive power and riches and wisdom and might and honor and
> glory and blessing."

By contrast, a number of versions do not base their translations on the original Greek text but on the Latin text, which is itself a translation of the Greek.  Such Latin-based translations include:

- Wycliffe
- Douay-Rheims
- Challoner's revision of DRB
- Confraternity Bible
- Knox Bible
- a few others

The Latin text is based on that of Jerome (400 AD) and the Clementine text (1592) which reads:

> dicentium voce magna : Dignus est Agnus, qui occisus est, accipere
> virtutem, et **divinitatem**, et sapientiam, et fortitudinem, et
> honorem, et gloriam, et benedictionem. = Saying with a loud voice: The
> Lamb that was slain is worthy to receive power, and **divinity**, and
> wisdom, and strength, and honour, and glory, and benediction.

Thus, the Latin text substitutes "divinity" for the Greek "riches/wealth".  The reason for this variation is unknown.  However, the Knox version has a footnote to Rev 5:12 saying:

> The Greek has 'riches', and it seems likely that the Latin version
> arose from a faulty reading.

Answer (score 2):

It is a textual/scribal error in Latin Vulgate, from which those versions like Douaye-Rheims (DR), Wycliffe etc are translated. It should be translated [divitias](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divitia#Latin) for riches, but it somehow became *[divinitatem](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV%7Cversion=NETfull%7Cversion=THGNT%7Cversion=VulgJ%7Cversion=DRC%7Creference=Rev.5.12&options=GNVUVH&display=INTERLEAVED)* in Rev 5:12.

A [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=revelations%205%3A12%20divinitatem%20%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BD%20variant%20latin%20vulgate&t=ffab&ia=web) search led to the Textual Criticism FB page where people suggested the textual corruption in Vulgate.

[Google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=divinitatem%20%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BD%20%20&hl=en&gl=in&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEdc3pY5zYbO3NUZSxPjouaGvnQTifw%3A1685706482467&ved=0ahUKEwimzdSAwqT_AhUZ7DgGHVYDDJwQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&sclient=gws-wiz-books) led to some references from (1875) *Union Review - Volume 13 - Page 75*, that mentions more errors such as in [1Peter 2:23](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV%7Cversion=NETfull%7Cversion=THGNT%7Cversion=VulgJ%7Cversion=DRC%7Creference=1Pet.2.23&options=GNVUVH&display=INTERLEAVED) *injuste* for *juste*. The Greek has dikaios  δικαίως (justly). Also see this [link](https://crosswire.org/study/parallelstudy.jsp?del=all&add=CopSahBible2&add=NA28&add=TR&add=NASB&add=Vulgate&Headings=Off&key=1Pet.2.23#cv).

> (ESV) When he was reviled, he did not revile in return; when he suffered, he did not threaten, but continued entrusting himself to him who judges **justly**.
> (DR): delivered himself to him that judged him **unjustly**.

Cambridge [commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/1_peter/2-23.htm) says,"The strange rendering in the Vulgate, “tradebat judicanti se injuste” as though the words referred not to God, but to Pilate, for which there is no Greek MS. authority, must be regarded as an arbitrary alteration made on the assumption that this was the crowning act of submissive patience". Although there are minor Greek mss listed without names in NA27 as variants which have "unjust", and they are obviously influenced by the Latin's error; Clementine's Latin translation has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The original Greek work translated as either 'riches' or 'power' is the work πλοῦτον, or plouton. It is typically translated as riches(17), 'of riches' (3) or wealth (2). The more modern translations (ESV, LSB, NASB, NKJV etc) - the ones where the phrasing seems unusual to us - are typically the more accurate as they have better resources available to translate from. Many of the older versions draw from more recent and fewer manuscripts making their translations more prone to error. Also as Dottard mentioned some of these translations are from the Latin Vulgate, so are translations of translations.

When questioning any translation or specific word (or in any study of the bible) I always try to keep an interlinear bible handy. [Biblehub's Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/) has a number of resources of this nature available.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, all of the translations involving divinity are derived from the Latin Vulgate.  But the question remains, why did Jerome (or some earlier translator) choose to translate πλοῦτος as *divinitas*?

The only possible explanation I could come up with - admittedly far-fetched - is that the word πλοῦτος was somehow connected with Πλούτων (*Ploutōn*), the Greek god of wealth.